# Powershell: Must provide a value expression on the right-hand side of the '-' operator

Tags: powershell-2.0

```
#GET TEXT FILE WITH LIST OF "SAMACCOUNTNAME" TO LIST VARIABLE
    $list = Get-Content C:\PSSCripts\listofusers.txt

#PULL INFORMATION FROM ACTIVE DIRECTORY TO USERRESULTS VARIABLE
    $UserResults = Get-AdUser -filter * -searchbase "OU=THISOU,DC=THISDOMAIN,DC=int" -Properties displayname

#DETERMINE IF USER IS IN THE TXT LIST

    foreach ($user in $UserResults)
    {
        if ($user.SamAccountName -in $list.SamAccountName)
        {
#ECHO THEIR NAME TO VERIFY

        write-host $user.displayName
        }
    }

#VERIFY USER TO BE OFFBOARDED VIA Y/N PROMPT - VISUALLY INSPECT LIST


    $choice = ""
    while ($choice -notmatch "[y|n]"){
    $choice = read-host "The following user profiles have been loaded for offboarding. Do you want to continue? Please Verify the users before continuing. (Y/N)"
    }

if ($choice -eq "y"){

        # LOOP THROUGH USERS AND APPLY CHANGES
        foreach ($user in $UserResults)
        {
            #DETERMINE IF USER IS IN TXT FILE
            if ($user.SamAccountName -in $list.SamAccountName)
                {
                # DISABLE ACCOUNT
                Disable-ADAccount -Identity $user

                # CHANGE DISPLAYNAME AND DESCRIPTION TO DISPLAY TERMINATED - $USER
                $newname = "Terminated - " + $user.displayName 
                Get-ADUser -Identity $user | Set-ADObject -Description $newname -DisplayName $newname

                # CHANGE USER PASSWORD TO "Password1"
                $password = "Password1" | ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText -Force
                Set-ADAccountPassword -NewPassword $password -Identity $user -Reset

                # MOVE USER TO DIFFERENT LOCATION, Disabled Users organizational unit
                Move-ADObject -Identity $user -TargetPath "OU=DisabledUsers,DC=THATDOMAIN,DC=int" -Confirm:$false
                }

        }



    }

else {write-host "Script aborted!"}
```

Getting the following error:
*You must provide a value expression on the right-hand side of the '-' operator. At :11 char:29

```
if ($user.SamAccountName - <<<< in $list.SamAccountName)
Category Info          : ParserError (:) [], ParseException
FullyQualifiedErrorID : ExpectedValueExpression
```

I have a list of users in a text file with the header SAMACCOUNTNAME. These users are being checked against the list of users in a particular OU. Powershell will echo the list of users in my text list to me (after having checked it against all the users in that OU in AD - to verify nothing is being offboarded / changed in error), prompt to verify (y|n) before moving forward and executing a script I wrote with the help of some redditors from /r/powershell earlier.

I'm not understanding why I'm getting this error, is

```
-in $list.SamAccountName
```

Not correct?

Thanks for the help, stackoverflow! First time posting, looking forward to getting better with Powershell and giving back to the community.

Answer (score 0):

You should use "-eq" or "-contains" (I am not sure what is a scalar value and what is an array in your program).